# Rotate Rename Numbering files using batch script

Tags: batch-file, rotation, rename

EDITE: I have more than 100 file

I have multiple files that I want to rotate every time I run a batch.

How to do it in every SUB-FOLDER?

[Here's the concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrinZ.jpg)

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: On a small scale level that is rather easy.  You would just do 5 rename commands. Rename 1 to 0.  Rename 2 to 1. Rename 3 to 2. Rename 4 to 3. Rename 0 to 4.  To iterate through subfolders you can use the `FOR /D /R` command. You have provided a very simplified example of what you want to do.  Things get complicated because if there were say 50 files in a directory you would not want to brute force the rename like that. So you would first have to figure out how many files are in the folder and then possibly use a `FOR /L` command to iterate through all the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i have more than 100 file. how do it?

Comment: What do you mean with "in every sub-folder"? Are the files splattered over sub(sub?)folders? Are there duplicate names?

Comment: @Stephan, same file (.jpg) in all subfolder.
rotate name file only in every folder.
If confusing, how to solve my problem only in one folder?

Comment: Why do you need it? May it be a [x-y-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)? Maybe a new (increased) number each time, your script runs can solve your problem?

Comment: I need like Squashman comment above, but for 100 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM get number of files:
set count=0
for %%a in (*.jpg) do set /A count+=1

REM rename them (decreasing by one):
for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
  set /a new=%%a-1
  ECHO ren %%a.jpg !new!.jpg
)
REM rename 0 to max
ECHO ren 0.jpg %count%.jpg
```

remove the `ECHO`s when you verified it's what you want.

Comment: your concept is right. as i want.

but run the batch, not respon for my images.

I have 100 images which is already named 1,2,3...100.

Please, I'm a beginner, give me the final script

Comment: Generally the idea is to read the answer before you decide to test and come back complaining of issues. **Read the last line of the answer!**

Comment: Tested again.
Thanks Stephan, You're my hero.